# How do I reload jQuery slideshow with jQuery show/hide event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I am using jQuery to show/hide divs on a page. Within each div, I have a jQuery slideshow. The first one works, but upon clicking through to next div, the slider is broken. (see: http://www.parker-gibson.com/mqm_test/hawkeye_beef.html). I am told I need to reload slider after every show/hide event, but I have no idea how. Not very jQuery literate. Thanks for any help!!

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Midwest Quality Meats</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="top-nav">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="hawkeye.html">Hawkeye Meats</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="#">...</a></li>-->
                <!--<li><a href="#">...</a></li>-->
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Meats</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="beef.html">Beef</a></li>
                <li><a href="pork.html">Pork</a></li>
                <li><a href="chicken.html">Chicken</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <a href="index.html" style="display:block; float:left; margin:0 95px 0 25px;"><img src="img/ribbon.png"></a>

        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li style="margin-right:15px;"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</div> <!--end top nav-->

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div id="nav spacer" style="width:960px; height:80px;">
</div>

<div id="meat-wrap">

<div id="cuts-container">
    <div id="hwk-beef-nav-top">
    </div>
    <div id="cuts">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="strip_btn" class="buttons"><h2>New York Strip Steak</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="tbone_btn" class="buttons"><h2>T-Bone Steak</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="sirloin_btn" class="buttons"><h2>Top Sirloin Steak</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="filet_btn" class="buttons"><h2>Sirloin Filet Steak</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="chuck_btn" class="buttons"><h2>Chuck Steak</h2></a></li>
        <li><a id="beefpatty_btn" class="buttons"><h2>Ground Beef Patty</h2></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="animal-nav">
    <a href="pork.html"><div id="pork-nav" style="border-right:1px solid #000;"></div></a>
    <a href="chicken.html"><div id="chicken-nav"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!---------------------new york strip------------------------->
<div id="strip">
<div id="cut-slider">
    <ul id="slider1" class="sliders">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/strip1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/strip-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/strip2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">New York Strip Steak</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end strip-->

<!---------------------t-bone------------------------->
<div id="tbone">
<div id="cut-slider">
    <ul id="slider2" class="sliders">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/tbone1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/tbone-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/tbone2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">T-Bone Steak</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end tbone-->

<!---------------------sirloin------------------------->
<div id="sirloin">
<div id="cut-slider">
    <ul id="slider3" class="sliders">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/sirloin1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/sirloin-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/sirloin2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Top Sirloin Steak</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end sirloin-->

<!---------------------filet------------------------->
<div id="filet">
<div id="cut-slider">
    <ul id="slider4" class="sliders">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/filet1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/filet-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/filet2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Sirloin Filet Steak</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end filet-->

<!---------------------chuck------------------------->
<div id="chuck">
<div id="cut-slider">
    <ul id="slider5" class="sliders">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/chuck1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/chuck-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/chuck2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Chuck Steak</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end chuck-->

<!---------------------beefpatty------------------------->
<div id="beefpatty">
<div id="cut-slider">
<ul id="slider6" class="sliders">
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/patty1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/patty-box.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="img/slider-img/patty2.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="details">
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Ground Beef Patty</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
    <h3>Name of cut:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">Breast</p>
    <h3>Flavor Profile:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.</p>
    <h3>Size:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">10-12 oz</p>
    <h3>Recommendations:</h3>
    <p class="detail-copy">It puts the lotion in the basket, or else it gets the hose again.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end beefpatty-->

</div> <!--end meat wrap-->

</div> <!--end container-->

<div id="footer"></div>

<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
    $('#slider2').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
    $('#slider3').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
    $('#slider4').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
    $('#slider5').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
    $('#slider6').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    auto: false,
    autoControls: false,
    pause: 3000,
    useCSS: false
});
});
</script>
<!--show/hide effects-->
<script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
  function hideContent() {
    var l = elements.length;
    while (l--) {
      $('#' + elements[l]).hide();
    }
  }
  var elements = ['strip', 'tbone', 'sirloin', 'filet', 'chuck', 'beefpatty'];

  hideContent();
  $('#strip').show();
  $("#strip_btn").addClass('active_btn');


  $('.buttons').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0]; //this gives you the target page id
    hideContent();
    $('.buttons').removeClass('active_btn');

    $('#' + page).show();
    $(this).addClass('active_btn');
    $('.sliders').bxSlider().reloadSlider();
  });
}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so like this:

You have ul elements which are sliders and have ids such as "slider1", "slider2".

Give those guys a class such as "sliders"

And then run:

```
$('.sliders').bxSlider().reloadSlider();
```

To reload the slider.

You can try it for yourself in the console. For example when you click on the second link: T-Bone Steak, the slider breaks. Then open up the console and run:

```
$('#slider2').bxSlider().reloadSlider();
```

To reload that slider.

Just give all of them a class and then on every click reload the whole class.

Optionally to optimize all of your code, give all of your links/buttons a class such as buttons and rewrite everything this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
function makeSlider($el) {
    $el.bxSlider({
      mode: 'horizontal',
      auto: false,
      autoControls: false,
      pause: 3000,
      useCSS: false
    });
    $el.addClass('activeSlider');
}



function hideContent() {
  var l = elements.length;
  while (l--) {
    $('#' + elements[l]).hide();
  }
}
var elements = ['strip', 'tbone', 'sirloin', 'filet', 'chuck', 'beefpatty'];

makeSlider($('#slider1'));
hideContent();
$('#strip').show();
$("#strip_btn").addClass('active_btn');


$('.buttons').click(function() {
  var page = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0]; //this gives you the target page id
  hideContent();
  $('.buttons').removeClass('active_btn');
  $('.activeSlider').bxSlider().destroySlider();
  $('.activeSlider').removeClass('activeSlider');


  $('#' + page).show();
  $(this).addClass('active_btn');
  makeSlider($('#'+page+' .sliders'));
});
});  
</script>
```

OK so by doing this we removed all the unnecessary sliders and have only one, which we construct and deconstruct whenever we show different pages.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it! You're right, it does work in console when I run that. I added the class "sliders" to all the ul elements, Where in the code do I run the $('.sliders').bxSlider().reloadSlider(); ?

Comment: In the click handlers. But actually you can also rewrite all those click handlers to be just one handler not 5 of them. Let me see if I can do that for you, give me a few min.

Comment: Man, you are saving my life right now. THANK YOU! Been beating my head against this for a while

Comment: OK, I rewrote all of your JS so you have just one click handler. Remember to give all the buttons a class such as buttons. This should all work but let me know if something bugs out and I'll help you debug.

Comment: thanks!! i edited the code above to reflect the changes, as well as the live site. looks like it's bugging out a bit...

Comment: OK, I can fix it but it will involve some rewriting of HTML. Send me an email (you can find it in my profile) so that we don't spam the comments here, and when we fix it I'll update the answer.